# YQL How to use wildcard in XPath

Tags: xpath, yql

I have a malformed page to scrape, and have had a hard time getting the correct XPath for YQL. I can scrape individual fields that I need using, for example:

```
//*[@id="cell_12345"]
```

But what I really need to do is return all elements who's ID begins with `cell_`. Something like:

```
//*[@id="cell_"*]
```

How do I do this?

Also, if anybody can point me to a good XPath reference it would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Something like

```
//*[starts-with(@id, 'ceil_')]
```

should do nicely.

As for an xpath reference, once you know the syntax and the axis, just any old function reference should help. This was the first one google: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp

Comment: Any idea how to fecth image and meta description from amazon.in/Seiko-Premier-Analog-Blue-Watch/dp/… ?